# How to passing size value to resequencer in dynamic way?

Tags: apache-camel

How can you pass a value straight from the header as integer to the size method?

```
from(...).resequence(body()).batch().size(${pass_some_value_from_header_as_integer}).timeout(4000L).to(....)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use a message header field to configure the [Resequencer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/resequence-eip.adoc) because the route is kind of "static" while the message header is a runtime value that can change for every message.

What should happen if the batch has collected 50 messages and the next sets the batch size to 10?

However, despite my doubts, the [BatchProcessor](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/BatchProcessor.java) of Camel (Resequencer extends BatchProcessor) knows an **Exchange Property named `Exchange.BATCH_SIZE`**.

No idea if this works, but you could give it a try and

- Set a default batch size in the route (initial value)
- Set the Exchange Property on the current message whenever you want to change the batch size. Obviously before you send the message to the Resequencer.

Set Exchange Property

```
.setProperty(Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, "yourValue")
```

or if you want to take the value from your message header

```
.setProperty(Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, header("yourHeaderName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. For now, I've solved the problem by using an aggregator that also sorts the order of messages. I know that it probably is not the perfect solution only workaround but it works for now. How will I have a moment trying to apply your solution.

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
      class SampleEventRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
          from(DIRECT_START)
              .process(exchange -> System.out.println("Input event : " + exchange.getIn().getBody()))
              .aggregate(header(CORRELATION_ID), new ResequencerStrategy())
              .completionSize(header(SIZE)) //here i can pass messages size in dynamic way
              .completionTimeout(2000)
              .log("${body}")
              .log("Completed by ${property.CamelAggregatedCompletedBy}")
              .split().body()
              .setBody(simple("${body.payload}"))
              .process(exchange -> System.out.println("Output event  : " + exchange.getIn().getBody()))
              .end();
        }
      }

@Value
class PayloadWrapper {

    private final String payload;
    private final int order;
    private final String correlationId;

}
```